# I cannot fit a Maxwell distribution due to "divide by zero encountered in log" error

Tags: scipy, distribution, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a [Maxwell distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html) with the values included in [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BNDWlmL4f_zxYgcNkcccfyEv7AJnrxw3/view?usp=sharing).

Since I need to force a loc of 0, I am using the expression:

```
params = st.maxwell.fit(values, floc=0)
```

However, this fails with a "divide by zero encountered in log" error:

I estimate that a pdf with loc=0 and a scale around 11000 would be quite good.

[image: PDF Example for this dataset]

How can I bypass this problem and make the fitting work?

Comment: Damn it, I had one job. Thx for noticing. I shared the wrong file. Can you try again plz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that maximizes the log-likelihood is triggering an underflow, because its default initial guess for the scale parameter is 1, which is pretty far from the actual optimum.  You can pass in a better guess to `fit` with the `scale` argument.  A good guess is provided by the method of moments, which in this case means using the sample mean to estimate the scale parameter.  The wikipedia page on the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) gives the formula for the mean μ in terms of the scale `a`.  Solving for `a` gives:

```
In [19]: a = np.mean(values)/(2*np.sqrt(2/np.pi))

In [20]: a
Out[20]: 10587.275841415043
```

Now pass that value to `fit` as the `scale` argument, which overrides the default initial value used by the optimization code:

```
In [21]: p = maxwell.fit(values, floc=0, scale=a)

In [22]: p
Out[22]: (0, 10455.558876443883)
```

That's the maximum likelihood estimate for the location (which you set to 0) and the scale `a`.